# Move chart labels of variables in opposite directions

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I couldn't find out how to do this anywhere so I thought I would post the solution now that I've figured it out.

I created a simple chart with labels based on a data set in long format (see below for `dat`). There are two lines and the labels overlap. I would like to move the labels for the upper chart up and for the lower chart down.

[image: Original Chart]

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

# sample data
dat <- data.frame(
  x = seq(1, 10, length.out = 10),
  y1 = seq(1, 5, length.out = 10),
  y2 = seq(1, 6, length.out = 10))

# convert to long format
dat <- dat %>% 
  gather(var, value, -x)

# plot it
ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = x, y = value, color = var)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_label(aes(label = value))
```

Comment: The `ggrepel` package was designed for exactly this, maybe take a look https://github.com/slowkow/ggrepel

Comment: @JackBrookes I actually do use `ggrepel` normally but I couldn't make it work in this case. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To move the labels in opposite directions, one can create a step function in `nudge_y` to multiply the upper line's labels by +1 times a nudge factor and the multiply the lower line's labels by -1 times the nudge factor:

```
# move labels in opposite directions
ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = x, y = value, color = var)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_label(aes(label = value), 
             nudge_y = ifelse(dat$var == "y2", 1, -1) * 1)
```

This produces the following chart with adjusted labels.

[image: Adjusted Chart]